# Ubuntu 14.04 stuck on "requesting acpi_cpufreq"

Tags: boot

Tried to install 14.04 64bit desktop version on an old EeePC (with asus 1001px and N450).

Install was successful, but on restart got no where beyond purple blank screen or flashing cursor in top left corner.

Recovery mode gets to:

```
...    
[0.406813] ACPI: Power Button [PWRF]
[0.407145] ACPI: Requesting acpi_cpufreq
[1.043873] Freeing initrd memory: 20504k freed
```

any thoughts on resolving the issue?

Thank you!

Comment: This is off topic for Stackoverflow since it isn't a programming related question. But have you tried booting with the option `acpi=off`

Comment: Oh yes! good point! Somewhat resolved by installing 32 bit version....d'oh. Thanks for the suggestion anyway!